Using \left and \right but also prevent very huge brackets for empty spaces

I want the image above to be something as this

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    x = \left( \frac{\sqrt{a + b}}{c \rlap{\vrule width 0.1pt depth 3em height 0em}} \right)^{k}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


Try replacing the () by the pmatrix env


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}



\begin{equation*}
    x = \left(
    \substack{\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{a + b}}{c}\\{\vrule width 0.1pt depth 3em height 0em}}
    \right)^{k}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


This is less widely applicable than the answer using \vcenter from the proposed duplicate question, since this suggest modifying the internals of the material inside the delimiters.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thank you for the feedback. I am interested in seeing your complete solution. I would appreciate if you could find an instance where your solution works and mine doesn't. I am here to learn :).
